# Why I'm getting errors after win_delay_load_hook.cc while npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

Trying to install Simplify-Docx from github.
Getting plenty of gyp errors, can't wrap my head around.

```
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Concert\docx2json-master\node_modules\contextify
    gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! contextify@0.1.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.15 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-29T18_24_50_333Z-debug.log
```

How do I track down the source of the error? I've installed pyton-java-jdk-microsoft builder kit and whatever else. Eager to give any other listings if needed, just don't know which, at the moment. Could it be that there's something wrong with my MSBuild.exe path? 'where msbuild' shows the correct path though.

Thank you!